# The cardinal of the set of all measures on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

It is a very simple question that I don't know how to do:

Let $M = \{\mu \colon \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R} \colon \mu \text{ is a measure}\}$

$$|M| = \ ?$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you say that the measure is into $\Bbb R$, do you mean that it only gives finite values?

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$, namely $2^{\aleph_0}$. Since $M$ is a set of functions between the two sets, its cardinality is bounded by the cardinality of $\Bbb{R^R}$ which is $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

On the other hand, given any subset $A\subseteq \Bbb R$, we can consider $\mu_A$ which is an atomic measure satisfying $\mu(\{x\})=1$ when $x\in A$ and $\mu(\{x\})=0$ otherwise. Namely the counting measure with respect to $A$. It is not hard to see that this gives a lower bound of $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ measures, so equality must hold.

Comment: Strictly speaking the question asks for measures $\mu : \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$, not $\mu : \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \to [0,\infty]$.  So the question really wants to count the *finite* measures.  The answer should be $2^{\aleph_0}$ by weak-* separability, but maybe there is an easier way to see that.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. Let's ask for clarification in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete separable, all Borel measures are regular so they are determined by their values on finite unions of rational intervals. It follows that there are continuum many Borel measures on reals.